# HTML layout error with <table align="left">

Tags: html, css

I have a page divided into sections, where each section has a header and some content. The content in each section is inserted from an external source, and I have discovered that when it is a table with an "align" attribute, the following header is displayed beginning at the point immediately after the end of the table on the same line/ Here's a minimal example:

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <style>
        div.header {
          background-color: lightblue;
          border: solid black;
          border-width: thin 0;
          width: 100%;
        }
        div.content {
          margin: 1em 2.5em 2em 2.5em;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="section">
        <div class="header">
          * Header 1
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <table align="left">  <!-- remove align="left" to correct layout -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                Something long enough to wrap over several lines.
              </td>
              <td >
                Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
                blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <div class="header">
          * Header 2
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          Anything.
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The above renders as follows:

[image]

If the `align="left"` attribute is removed from the `<table>` tag, it displays properly. I've tested this with several different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera) and it behaves the same way across all of them.

I have no control in my app over the content that appears in each section. Can anyone tell me (a) why this happens, and (b) is there any way to wrap the content in something which will always be rendered correctly?

Comment: `align="left" == float: left` do not use this parameter

Comment: You write - "is there any way to wrap the content in something which will always be rendered correctly". What do you mean? What result do you want to get?

Comment: Sergey: "The content in each section is inserted from an external source" so I have no choice in the matter. What I'm expecting is that the content of the first section will not be displayed on to of the second header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the `align` attribute is deprecated so I would reccomend looking at using flexbox instead - it solves all these issues.

Anyway, the reason why this is is  happening is because floats and aligns make things overlap. You need to use a tried and tested trick to fix this. This is to add `overflow: auto` onto your divs. Like this:

```css
div.header {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: solid black;
    border-width: thin 0;
    width: 100%;
}
div.content {
    margin: 1em 2.5em 2em 2.5em;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
    <div class="header">
      * Header 1
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <table align="left">  <!-- remove align="left" to correct layout -->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Something long enough to wrap over several lines.
                </td>
                <td >
                    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
                    blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="header">
        * Header 2
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Anything.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I know that align is deprecated, but the table is generated elsewhere, so I have no way to prevent it. But I don't understand why I have a float here anyway, since div and table are display:block by default... why don't they stack up on top of each other like block elements are supposed to? I'd be really grateful for an explanation...

Comment: floats and aligns are mostly the same thing, and when you float and align, things get taken out of normal flow, so `display: block` doesnt really do much. We can often use this to make columns and stuff like that so I suppose thats a bonus.